# Mean Value Theorem for measurable functions

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Suppose that $f$ is a Lebesgue measurable function, $\Omega$ is an open bounded domain in $R^{N}$ and
$$
\int_{\Omega}f(x)dx=|\Omega|m,\qquad m\ \ is\ \ a\ \  constant.
$$
Under which condition(s) on $f$ we can say $f\equiv m$ ?

Comment: The integral equality is necessary but nowhere near sufficient in general. Even in first-year calculus, every single nonzero integral on a finite interval satisfies such an equality for some constant $m$.

Comment: $f$ being constant is a sufficient condition.

Comment: For fixed $\Omega$ this alone is not enough.  If the equation is true for arbitrary $\Omega$,then you can say that $f=m$ a.e.